# How can I modify the regex in this script to parse ngrep instead of netstat?

Tags: regex, perl

I am currently using a Perl version of a DDoS Deflate script, which parses `netstat` for the total number of IPs connected in order to apply IP ban rules.

Currently the script is parsing `netstat` with this regex:

```
my %active_conns_by_ip = ( );
for my $line ( split /^/, `netstat -ntu --protocol=inet` ) {
    if ( $line =~ /^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+):\S+/i ) {
        my $ip = $1;
```

(See sample output of `nestat -ntu --protocol=inet` [here](http://prntscr.com/8ew551).)

Basically what I want to achieve is a change in the script regex that will parse the `$ip` from the following command instead:

```
ngrep -il -d eth0 -W byline "x-forwarded-for" "port 80" | grep -i x-forwarded-for
```

The output of `ngrep` has the following format:

```
X-Forwarded-For: 46.166.xx.xx
X-Forwarded-For: 78.143.xx.xx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
if ( $line =~ /^X-Forwarded-For:\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/i ) {
  my $ip = $1;

}
```